# Make SVG transparent with d3 on leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, leaflet

I am following Mike Bostock's [tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/) on how to display a `(geo)json` on a `leaflet map` through `d3`.

It works - sort of. 
When I try to display this file [here](http://eric.clst.org/Stuff/USGeoJSON) (the geoJSON "US States") I get a black block on my map isntead of the outlines of the states.[image: screenshot]

Any ideas why?

Comment: Check you stylesheet. Make sure to add the proper `background-color`property

Comment: @pistou where would I add that?

Comment: Check [this code](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/) from your tutorial ; do you have the same `<style></style` part? The `fill` and `fill-opacity` may be what you're looking for

Comment: @pistou thats it. Thanks! Wanna write it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have an issue with you stylesheet.

The source code of [your tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/) has the following :

```
<style>
path {
  fill: #000;
  fill-opacity: .2;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

path:hover {
  fill: brown;
  fill-opacity: .7;
}
</style>
```

You should play with the `fill` and `fill-opacity` properties to match your needs.